# libGDX android onPause listener

Tags: android, libgdx

In my `libGDX` game I want to display pause dialog when `onPause()` occur in android `AndroidApplication` class

Can some one tell me how to implement callback from `Android` to `libGDX` code not reverse?

Should I first need to make `request` from `libGDX Game Screen` to the `Android` class, and then fire `callback` from `Android` to `libGDX` when `onPause()` occur ? OR there is simple way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pause()` and `resume()` is the life cycle method of `ApplicationListener` interface.

On Android `pause()` method is called when the Home button is pressed or an incoming call is received.

```
onPause() --> pause()
```

Override this method and show your dialog. No need of any callback or anything else.